# why list reversing returns None?in python

Tags: python

I use reverse, but it returns me None, can you help?

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
print('Reversed List = ',ls.reverse())
```

this is result:

```
('List = ', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
('Reversed List = ', None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `reverse` does not return a list, it mutates the list in place. A method with no return always returns `None`. Try:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
ls.reverse()
print('Reversed List = ',ls)
```

Alternatively you could use a step value with slice notation. This also has the effect of not mutating the input list:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
print('Reversed List = ',ls[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`reverse` method does the operations "in-place", so you need to do:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
ls.reverse()
print('Reversed List = ', ls)
```

Or use `reversed` that isn't "in-place":

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
print('Reversed List = ', list(reversed(ls)))
```

Or a cool slicing method:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print('List = ',ls)
print('Reversed List = ', ls[::-1])
```